# "Pay-for" vs. "for-pay"

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, word-order, compounds

Is *pay-for* or *for-pay* the correct word? For example, which of these two sentences is correct?

> - This is a pay-for product.
> - This is a for-pay product.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usage stats from the [Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA)](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) and the [British National Corpus (BNC)](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/) look as follows:

```
            COCA    BNC      

for-pay      22      0
pay-for       0      0
```

In other words, *pay-for* is not an option on either side of the pond, while *for-pay* is only used in American English.

The most common collocates are *services* (3) and *version* (2). There is not a single cite for a *for-pay product*, but then again the sample size is very small.

My personal advice: while *for-pay* is self-explanatory enough to be used in informal contexts, in formal writing you might wish to reword. There isn't a single one-size-fits-all adjective; depending on context anything from *commercial* to *premium* might or might not work. You might have to restructure the entire phrase ("available for a fee" or some such).

See also: [What is the opposite of “free” as in “free of charge”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56704/what-is-the-opposite-of-free-as-in-free-of-charge)

Comment: Both *pay-for-play* and *$X-for-pay* both come to mind here.

Comment: Perhaps there's a US/UK split here. I don't come across *pay-for* or *for-pay*, but we in the UK are quite familiar with [paid-for products](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22a+paid-for+product%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) / [services](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22a+paid-for+service%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). The fact that the descriptor is past tense doesn't necessarily mean you've already paid for it - just that it's a product/service that's *not given away free*.

Comment: *pay-per* is also a common variation, when the service has a well-known noun associated with it. For instance, a television broadcast may be referred to as *pay-per-view*.

Answer (score 1):

People say "for-pay", but I think a real word like "commercial" or "professional" would be better.